# auto update value column based on other column values in sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint

I'm new to SharePoint.
I would like to create a list as below:

[image]

When I input some project with Start Date estimated. I want system auto generate the date for Design (Start Date + 7days), Construction (Design Date + 40days), Opening Date (Construction date + 7days).

And when I quick edit. If I change date at Design field. System will auto update new value for Construction (+40) and Opening Date (+7). If I change Construction Date, system will update new date for Opening Date.

Can you help me how to do this?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

Create the last three fields as formula fields in your SharePoint list.

You can then use similar formulas to excel to get your desired result.

Cheers

Truez